# c++ opencv orb detect function can't get parameter

Tags: c++, opencv, orb

I am trying to match two pictures with orb of opencv3 in visual studio 2017. First, I read Gray image matrix from a txt file into a 64x64 grey picture, and then I pre-treat the image. Image is read successfully, but when I am about to use detect function of orb, bug happens and I didn't know what was wrong. Here's my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>

#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#define rows 64
#define cols 64
#define MAXV 100
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int grey, i, j;
char div;
float x1, y1, x2, y2, vx, vy, vxbar, vybar;
clock_t tm1, tm2, tm3, tm4;

fstream file;
file.open("gray.txt");
Mat img_1 = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat img_2 = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat img_blur = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8UC1);


for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < cols - 1; j++)
    {
        //file >> TrainData.at<float>(i, j);
        file >> grey >> div;
        img_1.at<uchar>(i, j) = grey;
    }
    file >> grey;
    img_1.at<uchar>(i, cols - 1) = grey;
}

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < cols - 1; j++)
    {

        file >> grey >> div;
        img_2.at<uchar>(i, j) = grey;
    }
    file >> grey;
    img_2.at<uchar>(i, cols - 1) = grey;
}


equalizeHist(img_1, img_1);
equalizeHist(img_2, img_2);




vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;


Ptr<ORB> orb = ORB::create(500, 1.2f, 1, 7, 0, 2, ORB::HARRIS_SCORE, 23, 1);   

orb->detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
orb->detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

// -- Stpe 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors) 

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
orb->compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
orb->compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);
```

And here's the screenshots of bug report:

[image]

[image]

the relevant code is

```
orb->detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
```

and the error report:

```
install and test opencv.exe has triggered a breakpoint. occurred
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant bits of code and error messages into your post rather than leaving them in external images.

Comment: I apologize for my rudeness and actually I hope the screenshots can help someone solve my problem intuitively. Now I have re-edited it as your command. Longing for your help.